# can i use class of managed package for further development

Tags: apex, managed-package

```
public class checkManagedData {
    public void checkManagedMethod(){
        EMPYRAMDM.KeyFormationTriggerController jjj=new EMPYRAMDM.KeyFormationTriggerController();
    }
}
```

`KeyFormationTriggerController` is a class of Managed Package.EMPYRAMDM is Prefix.

Error:

> Compile Error: Type is not visible: keyformationtriggercontroller at
>   line 5 column 49.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only interact with global classes, interfaces, and methods within a managed package. In addition, you can only extend classes that are virtual or abstract.